# Рекурсивный перебор строк

Tags: python

> В алфавите языке племени «тумба-юмба» четыре буквы: «K», «L», «M» и
>   «N». Нужно вывести на экран все возможные слова, состоящие из n букв
>   (n>1), в которых вторая буква «K». Подсчитайте количество таких слов.

Сейчас я могу только перебрать все возможные варианты :/

```
def TumbaWords(word, alphabet, n):
    if n < 1:
        print(word)
        return
    for c in alphabet:
        TumbaWords(word+c, alphabet, n - 1) 
        x = list(word)

n = int(input())
TumbaWords("","KLMN", n)
```

Comment: Каков будет вопрос?

Comment: Вам точно нужна рекурсия? В питоне она довольно ограниченная по глубине. Лучше как-то через циклы решить. Да и вообще данная задача решается скорее алгебраически, а не перебором.

Comment: @Эникейщик вопрос в оптимизации, вероятно

Comment: @CrazyElf, для этой задачи глубина рекурсии будет равна 3. Уж на это-то питона хватит ))

Comment: @Xander А разве не 4*(n-1)? :)  Хотя смотря, как считать, но, в общем, на n тоже будет завязано

Comment: @CrazyElf, а точно, это я невнимательно условие прочитал

Comment: количество = `4 * 1 * 4 * ... всего n сомножителей ... * 4`. Другими словами `4**(n - 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Решение без рекурсии

Поскольку нужно не посчитать их количество, а вывести на экран, сделать это действительно можно только перебором. Но перебирать второй символ бессмысленно, потому количество вариантов для перебора сокращается сразу вчетверо. Могу предложить такой вариант:

```py
n = int(input('N > '))

alphabet = ['K', 'L', 'M', 'N']
res = ['KK', 'LK', 'MK', 'NK']

def extend(d: dict, alphabet: dict) -> dict:
  return [item + a for item in d for a in alphabet if type(a) == type('a')]


if n > 2: 
  for i in range(n-2):
    res = extend(res, alphabet)

print(res)
print('Всего слов', len(res))
```

Результат:

```
N > 5
['KKKKK', 'KKKKL', 'KKKKM', 'KKKKN', 'KKKLK', 'KKKLL', 'KKKLM', 'KKKLN', 'KKKMK', 'KKKML', 'KKKMM', 'KKKMN', 'KKKNK', 'KKKNL', 'KKKNM', 'KKKNN', 'KKLKK', 'KKLKL', 'KKLKM', 'KKLKN', 'KKLLK', 'KKLLL', 'KKLLM', 'KKLLN', 'KKLMK', 'KKLML', 'KKLMM', 'KKLMN', 'KKLNK', 'KKLNL', 'KKLNM', 'KKLNN', 'KKMKK', 'KKMKL', 'KKMKM', 'KKMKN', 'KKMLK', 'KKMLL', 'KKMLM', 'KKMLN', 'KKMMK', 'KKMML', 'KKMMM', 'KKMMN', 'KKMNK', 'KKMNL', 'KKMNM', 'KKMNN', 'KKNKK', 'KKNKL', 'KKNKM', 'KKNKN', 'KKNLK', 'KKNLL', 'KKNLM', 'KKNLN', 'KKNMK', 'KKNML', 'KKNMM', 'KKNMN', 'KKNNK', 'KKNNL', 'KKNNM', 'KKNNN', 'LKKKK', 'LKKKL', 'LKKKM', 'LKKKN', 'LKKLK', 'LKKLL', 'LKKLM','LKKLN', 'LKKMK', 'LKKML', 'LKKMM', 'LKKMN', 'LKKNK', 'LKKNL', 'LKKNM', 'LKKNN', 'LKLKK', 'LKLKL', 'LKLKM', 'LKLKN', 'LKLLK', 'LKLLL', 'LKLLM', 'LKLLN', 'LKLMK', 'LKLML', 'LKLMM', 'LKLMN', 'LKLNK', 'LKLNL', 'LKLNM', 'LKLNN', 'LKMKK', 'LKMKL', 'LKMKM', 'LKMKN', 'LKMLK', 'LKMLL', 'LKMLM', 'LKMLN', 'LKMMK', 'LKMML', 'LKMMM', 'LKMMN', 'LKMNK', 'LKMNL', 'LKMNM', 'LKMNN', 'LKNKK', 'LKNKL', 'LKNKM', 'LKNKN', 'LKNLK', 'LKNLL', 'LKNLM', 'LKNLN', 'LKNMK', 'LKNML', 'LKNMM', 'LKNMN', 'LKNNK', 'LKNNL', 'LKNNM', 'LKNNN', 'MKKKK', 'MKKKL', 'MKKKM', 'MKKKN', 'MKKLK', 'MKKLL', 'MKKLM', 'MKKLN', 'MKKMK', 'MKKML', 'MKKMM', 'MKKMN', 'MKKNK', 'MKKNL', 'MKKNM', 'MKKNN', 'MKLKK', 'MKLKL', 'MKLKM', 'MKLKN', 'MKLLK', 'MKLLL', 'MKLLM','MKLLN', 'MKLMK', 'MKLML', 'MKLMM', 'MKLMN', 'MKLNK', 'MKLNL', 'MKLNM', 'MKLNN', 'MKMKK', 'MKMKL', 'MKMKM', 'MKMKN', 'MKMLK', 'MKMLL', 'MKMLM', 'MKMLN', 'MKMMK', 'MKMML', 'MKMMM', 'MKMMN', 'MKMNK', 'MKMNL', 'MKMNM', 'MKMNN', 'MKNKK', 'MKNKL', 'MKNKM', 'MKNKN', 'MKNLK', 'MKNLL', 'MKNLM', 'MKNLN', 'MKNMK', 'MKNML', 'MKNMM', 'MKNMN', 'MKNNK', 'MKNNL', 'MKNNM', 'MKNNN', 'NKKKK', 'NKKKL', 'NKKKM', 'NKKKN', 'NKKLK', 'NKKLL', 'NKKLM', 'NKKLN', 'NKKMK', 'NKKML', 'NKKMM', 'NKKMN', 'NKKNK', 'NKKNL', 'NKKNM', 'NKKNN', 'NKLKK', 'NKLKL', 'NKLKM', 'NKLKN', 'NKLLK', 'NKLLL', 'NKLLM', 'NKLLN', 'NKLMK', 'NKLML', 'NKLMM', 'NKLMN', 'NKLNK', 'NKLNL', 'NKLNM', 'NKLNN', 'NKMKK', 'NKMKL', 'NKMKM', 'NKMKN', 'NKMLK', 'NKMLL', 'NKMLM','NKMLN', 'NKMMK', 'NKMML', 'NKMMM', 'NKMMN', 'NKMNK', 'NKMNL', 'NKMNM', 'NKMNN', 'NKNKK', 'NKNKL', 'NKNKM', 'NKNKN', 'NKNLK', 'NKNLL', 'NKNLM', 'NKNLN', 'NKNMK', 'NKNML', 'NKNMM', 'NKNMN', 'NKNNK', 'NKNNL', 'NKNNM', 'NKNNN']
Всего слов 256
```

## UPD: рекурсивное решение

Но если рекурсия не является обязательной, лучше использовать вариант выше

```py
n = int(input('N > '))

alphabet = ['K', 'L', 'M', 'N']
res = ['KK', 'LK', 'MK', 'NK']

def extend(d: dict, alphabet: dict, l: int) -> dict:
  if len(d[0]) >= l:
    return d  
  return extend([item + a for item in d for a in alphabet if type(a) == type('a')], alphabet, l)

res = extend(res, alphabet, n)

print(res)
print('Всего слов', len(res))
```

Результат:

```
N > 5
['KKKKK', 'KKKKL', 'KKKKM', 'KKKKN', 'KKKLK', 'KKKLL', 'KKKLM', 'KKKLN', 'KKKMK', 'KKKML', 'KKKMM', 'KKKMN', 'KKKNK', 'KKKNL', 'KKKNM', 'KKKNN', 'KKLKK', 'KKLKL', 'KKLKM', 'KKLKN', 'KKLLK', 'KKLLL', 'KKLLM', 'KKLLN', 'KKLMK', 'KKLML', 'KKLMM', 'KKLMN', 'KKLNK', 'KKLNL', 'KKLNM', 'KKLNN', 'KKMKK', 'KKMKL', 'KKMKM', 'KKMKN', 'KKMLK', 'KKMLL', 'KKMLM', 'KKMLN', 'KKMMK', 'KKMML', 'KKMMM', 'KKMMN', 'KKMNK', 'KKMNL', 'KKMNM', 'KKMNN', 'KKNKK', 'KKNKL', 'KKNKM', 'KKNKN', 'KKNLK', 'KKNLL', 'KKNLM', 'KKNLN', 'KKNMK', 'KKNML', 'KKNMM', 'KKNMN', 'KKNNK', 'KKNNL', 'KKNNM', 'KKNNN', 'LKKKK', 'LKKKL', 'LKKKM', 'LKKKN', 'LKKLK', 'LKKLL', 'LKKLM','LKKLN', 'LKKMK', 'LKKML', 'LKKMM', 'LKKMN', 'LKKNK', 'LKKNL', 'LKKNM', 'LKKNN', 'LKLKK', 'LKLKL', 'LKLKM', 'LKLKN', 'LKLLK', 'LKLLL', 'LKLLM', 'LKLLN', 'LKLMK', 'LKLML', 'LKLMM', 'LKLMN', 'LKLNK', 'LKLNL', 'LKLNM', 'LKLNN', 'LKMKK', 'LKMKL', 'LKMKM', 'LKMKN', 'LKMLK', 'LKMLL', 'LKMLM', 'LKMLN', 'LKMMK', 'LKMML', 'LKMMM', 'LKMMN', 'LKMNK', 'LKMNL', 'LKMNM', 'LKMNN', 'LKNKK', 'LKNKL', 'LKNKM', 'LKNKN', 'LKNLK', 'LKNLL', 'LKNLM', 'LKNLN', 'LKNMK', 'LKNML', 'LKNMM', 'LKNMN', 'LKNNK', 'LKNNL', 'LKNNM', 'LKNNN', 'MKKKK', 'MKKKL', 'MKKKM', 'MKKKN', 'MKKLK', 'MKKLL', 'MKKLM', 'MKKLN', 'MKKMK', 'MKKML', 'MKKMM', 'MKKMN', 'MKKNK', 'MKKNL', 'MKKNM', 'MKKNN', 'MKLKK', 'MKLKL', 'MKLKM', 'MKLKN', 'MKLLK', 'MKLLL', 'MKLLM','MKLLN', 'MKLMK', 'MKLML', 'MKLMM', 'MKLMN', 'MKLNK', 'MKLNL', 'MKLNM', 'MKLNN', 'MKMKK', 'MKMKL', 'MKMKM', 'MKMKN', 'MKMLK', 'MKMLL', 'MKMLM', 'MKMLN', 'MKMMK', 'MKMML', 'MKMMM', 'MKMMN', 'MKMNK', 'MKMNL', 'MKMNM', 'MKMNN', 'MKNKK', 'MKNKL', 'MKNKM', 'MKNKN', 'MKNLK', 'MKNLL', 'MKNLM', 'MKNLN', 'MKNMK', 'MKNML', 'MKNMM', 'MKNMN', 'MKNNK', 'MKNNL', 'MKNNM', 'MKNNN', 'NKKKK', 'NKKKL', 'NKKKM', 'NKKKN', 'NKKLK', 'NKKLL', 'NKKLM', 'NKKLN', 'NKKMK', 'NKKML', 'NKKMM', 'NKKMN', 'NKKNK', 'NKKNL', 'NKKNM', 'NKKNN', 'NKLKK', 'NKLKL', 'NKLKM', 'NKLKN', 'NKLLK', 'NKLLL', 'NKLLM', 'NKLLN', 'NKLMK', 'NKLML', 'NKLMM', 'NKLMN', 'NKLNK', 'NKLNL', 'NKLNM', 'NKLNN', 'NKMKK', 'NKMKL', 'NKMKM', 'NKMKN', 'NKMLK', 'NKMLL', 'NKMLM','NKMLN', 'NKMMK', 'NKMML', 'NKMMM', 'NKMMN', 'NKMNK', 'NKMNL', 'NKMNM', 'NKMNN', 'NKNKK', 'NKNKL', 'NKNKM', 'NKNKN', 'NKNLK', 'NKNLL', 'NKNLM', 'NKNLN', 'NKNMK', 'NKNML', 'NKNMM', 'NKNMN', 'NKNNK', 'NKNNL', 'NKNNM', 'NKNNN']
Всего слов 256
```

Answer (score 3):

Более гибкое решение без создания списка первых двух букв:

```
import itertools

def TumbaWords(alphabet, n):
    words = list(itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=n-1))
    for word in words:
        word = list(word)
        seq = [word[0], "K"] + word[1:]
        print("".join(seq))

n = int(input())
TumbaWords("KLMN", n)
```

Answer (score -1):

В принципе, в заданиях такого плана, можно использовать следующее:
Количество вариаций возводим в степень которая равна количеству комбинаций.
Проще говоря, 4 возводим в 4 степень и получаем 256!!!

Так и с замком работает:
4 колеса по 10 цифр на каждом.
10 в четвертой степени = 10000
Ну, и логично, что 4 колесика - число 9999 + вариация 0000.
То есть, 10 тысяч комбинаций.